# Sd card not coming in Android 2.2

Tags: android

I am facing a strange problem. when i am creating an emulator targeting Android 1.5 then emulator SD card is coming but when i am creating an emulator targeting Android 2.2 then emulator SD card is not coming. I an unable to solve this problem.. i think for this reason when i am opening emulator camera it is force closing automatically.. can any body help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to create AVD from eclipse and select the 2.2 SDK. Just beneath to that you can specify the size of SDcard.

Comment: i am doing everything required.. it is coming in Android 1.5 but not coming in above 1.5